# how to use the following meta tag to redirect the user

Tags: php

I would like to know what is the proper syntax for writing the following? because the `$tid` doesn't look right in sublime text...

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=forum_main.php?act=topic&id='.$tid.'>";
```

Comment: Can I just do this as well? echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=forum_main.php?act=topic&id='.$tid>";

Answer (score 0):

you have quotes mistake in your code, use like this

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=forum_main.php?act=topic&id='".$tid."'>";
```

Comment: @piano0011 glad to help